# Can a skill carry over through salvaging?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I've been trying to salvage a buckler I bought with +1 finesse on it over and over, but I never get anything worth anything out of it.  Am I wasting my time?  It's a blue buckler, and the only special properties it has is the skill.  I've done this maybe fifteen times now, and I am getting different things, so it's not that the results of my salvage are set in stone. I'm just wondering if it's even possible to get an item out of it that has the +1 skill on it?

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because I'm not 100% sure but I think the only way to get a +1 to your attributes is through an Epic Gems. You can make them when you have really high sagecrafting.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot salvage any parts that enhance an attribute.  You can only salvage parts that you see add elemental damage, damage, hp, mana, etc,...

Edit:

I just tested a theory.  you can make a lot of money off of items that have +1 to an attribute tree.  An item without it sold for about 14k while an item with it sold for about 54k.  So, consider selling it later instead of salvaging it.